# create custom module for pdf manipulation

Tags: kofax

I want to create a custom Kofax module. When it comes to the batch processing the scanned documents get converted to PDF files. I want to fetch these PDF files, manipulate them (add a custom footer to the PDF document) and hand them back to Kofax.

So what I know so far:

- create Kofax export scripts
- add a custom module to Kofax

I have the **APIRef.chm** (Kofax.Capture.SDK.CustomModule) and the **CMSplit** as an example project. Unfortunately I struggle getting into it. Are there any resources out there showing step by step how to get into custom module development?

So I know that the `IBatch` interface represents one selected batch and the `IBatchCollection` represents the collection of all batches.

I would just like to know how to setup a "Hello World" example and could add my code to it and I think I don't even need a WinForms application because I only need to manipulate the PDF files and that's it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I realized that your question was rather about how to create a custom module in general, allow me to add another answer. Start with a C# Console Application.

## Add Required Assemblies

Below assemblies are required by a custom module. All of them reside in the KC's binaries folder (by default `C:\Program Files (x86)\Kofax\CaptureSS\ServLib\Bin` on a server).

[image: references]

## Setup Part

Add a new `User Control` and `Windows Form` for setup. This is purely optional - a CM might not even have a setup form, but I'd recommend adding it regardless. The user control is the most important part, here - it will add the menu entry in KC Administration, and initialize the form itself:

```cs
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface ISetupForm
{
    [DispId(1)]
    AdminApplication Application { set; }
    [DispId(2)]
    void ActionEvent(int EventNumber, object Argument, out int Cancel);
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("Quipu.KC.CM.Setup")]
public class SetupUserControl : UserControl, ISetupForm
{
    private AdminApplication adminApplication;

    public AdminApplication Application
    {
        set
        {
            value.AddMenu("Quipu.KC.CM.Setup", "Quipu.KC.CM - Setup", "BatchClass");
            adminApplication = value;
        }
    }

    public void ActionEvent(int EventNumber, object Argument, out int Cancel)
    {
        Cancel = 0;

        if ((KfxOcxEvent)EventNumber == KfxOcxEvent.KfxOcxEventMenuClicked && (string)Argument == "Quipu.KC.CM.Setup")
        {
            SetupForm form = new SetupForm();
            form.ShowDialog(adminApplication.ActiveBatchClass);
        }
    }

}
```

## Runtime Part

Since I started with a console application, I could go ahead and put all the logic into `Program.cs`. Note that is for demo-purposes only, and I would recommend adding specific classes and forms later on. The example below logs into Kofax Capture, grabs the next available batch, and just outputs its name.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, eventArgs) => KcAssemblyResolver.Resolve(eventArgs);
        Run(args);
        return;
    }


    static void Run(string[] args)
    {
        // start processing here
        // todo encapsulate this to a separate class!

        // login to KC
        var login = new Login();
        login.EnableSecurityBoost = true;
        login.Login();
        login.ApplicationName = "Quipu.KC.CM";
        login.Version = "1.0";
        login.ValidateUser("Quipu.KC.CM.exe", false, "", "");

        var session = login.RuntimeSession;

        // todo add timer-based polling here (note: mutex!)
        var activeBatch = session.NextBatchGet(login.ProcessID);

        Console.WriteLine(activeBatch.Name);

        activeBatch.BatchClose(
            KfxDbState.KfxDbBatchReady,
            KfxDbQueue.KfxDbQueueNext,
            0,
            "");

        session.Dispose();
        login.Logout();

    }
}
```

## Registering, COM-Visibility, and more

Registering a Custom Module is done via `RegAsm.exe` and ideally with the help of an AEX file. Here's an example - please refer to the documentation for more details and all available settings.

```
[Modules]
Minimal CM

[Minimal CM]
RuntimeProgram=Quipu/CM/Quipu.KC.CM/Quipu.KC.CM.exe
ModuleID=Quipu.KC.CM.exe
Description=Minimal Template for a Custom Module in C#
Version=1.0
SupportsTableFields=True
SupportsNonImageFiles=True
SetupProgram=Minimal CM Setup

[Setup Programs]
Minimal CM Setup

[Minimal CM Setup]
Visible=0
OCXFile=Quipu/CM/Quipu.KC.CM/Quipu.KC.CM.exe
ProgID=Quipu.KC.CM.Setup
```

Last but not least, make sure your assemblies are COM-visible:
[image: com-visible]

I put up the entire code on [GitHub](https://github.com/redlynx/Quipu.KC.CM), feel free to fork it. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your example and I think I got it :) If you want to have a look these are my lines of code https://pastebin.com/BaTbz1Rb . I tested it and I think I only have to add the PDF manipulation in the `BatchProcessor` now. I will add a bounty to this question to reward your effort :) (But have to wait 24 hours ...)

Comment: I also have a question about your setup form but I moved this question to another thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813426/create-setup-form-for-custom-module Not sure if I misunderstood your concept :S

Answer (score 1):

Kofax exposes a batch as an XML, and `DBLite` is basically a wrapper for said XML. The structure is explained in AcBatch.htm and AcDocs.htm (to be found under the CaptureSV directory). Here's the basic idea (just documents are shown):

- AscentCaptureRuntime

  - Batch

    - Documents

      - Document

A single document has child elements itself such as pages, and multiple properties such as `Confidence`, `FormTypeName`, and `PDFGenerationFileName`. This is what you want. Here's how you would navigate down the document collection, storing the filename in a variable named `pdfFileName`:

```cs
IACDataElement runtime = activeBatch.ExtractRuntimeACDataElement(0);

IACDataElement batch = runtime.FindChildElementByName("Batch");
var documents = batch.FindChildElementByName("Documents").FindChildElementsByName("Document");
for (int i = 0; i < documents.Count; i++)
{
    // 1-based index in kofax
    var pdfFileName = documents[i + 1]["PDFGenerationFileName"];
}
```

Personally, I don't like this structure, so I created my own wrapper for their wrapper, but that's up to you.

With regard to the custom module itself, the sample shipped is already a decent start. Basically, you would have a basic form that shows up if the user launches the module manually - which is entirely optional if work happens in the back, preferably as Windows Service. I like to start with a console application, adding forms only when needed. Here, I would launch the form as follows, or start the service. Note that I have different branches in case the user wants to install my Custom Module as service:

```cs
else if (Environment.UserInteractive)
{
    // run as module
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new RuntimeForm(args));

}
    else
    {
        // run as service
        ServiceBase.Run(new CustomModuleService());
    }
}
```

The runtime for itself just logs you into Kofax Capture, registers event handlers, and processes batch by batch:

```cs
// login to KC
cm = new CustomModule();
cm.Login("", "");

// add progress event handlers
cm.BatchOpened += Cm_BatchOpened;
cm.BatchClosed += Cm_BatchClosed;
cm.DocumentOpened += Cm_DocumentOpened;
cm.DocumentClosed += Cm_DocumentClosed;
cm.ErrorOccured += Cm_ErrorOccured;

// process in background thread so that the form does not freeze
worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (s, a) => Process();
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Then, your CM fetches the next batch. This can either make use of Kofax' Batch Notification Service, or be based on a timer. For the former, just handle the `BatchAvailable` event of the session object:

```cs
session.BatchAvailable += Session_BatchAvailable;
```

For the latter, define a timer - preferrably with a configurable polling interval:

```cs
pollTimer.Interval = pollIntervalSeconds * 1000;
pollTimer.Elapsed += PollTimer_Elapsed;
pollTimer.Enabled = true;
```

When the timer elapses, you could do the following:

```cs
private void PollTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    mutex.WaitOne();
    ProcessBatches();
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Wolfgang. Your PDF snippet works fine, I tested it for the "Separate" example. I just saw that the code example provides a polling to fetch the batches but unfortunately I don't understand your application example. What is `CustomModule` (your provided class) ?

Comment: Edit: I was told timers are bad / dangerous. So do really I have to use timers and try a polling each X seconds? Are there any "better" solutions?

Comment: `CustomModule` is my custom class, and this is entirely optional. I updated my answer to include polling - with and without Batch Notification Service (BNS). Timers aren't bad at all, and BNS is your alternative. Hope this helps, please feel free to add more questions.

Comment: Thanks again. I created a snippet showing the current project https://pastebin.com/4z9XTV3h Your explanations are really good but I'm struggling setting up the basics. So would you mind telling me what's missing when I only want to manipulate each generated PDF file?

Comment: Maybe I don't need all those methods from their `BatchManager` class

Comment: Added another answer as I felt this covers the general approach much better. There's a free sample on GitHub, but if you're interested in purchasing templates for KC or need general guidance, please feel free to reach out: https://www.smartcap-its.com/kontakt/ (Disclaimer: I work for them).