# Create a Custom Module Kofax for data validation through webservice

Tags: kofax

I have created a basic Custom Module (KC.CM.Divalto) that aims to:

- read data extracted from a batch
- call a webservice
- redirect to validation module or PDF generator depending on webservice response

[image]

I will output data into MessageBox for beginning.

At this stage, I read previous questions concerning Custom Modules and it helped me have a valid exe:

- [create setup form for custom module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813426/create-setup-form-for-custom-module)
- [create custom module for pdf manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709249/create-custom-module-for-pdf-manipulation)

  ```
  internal class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, eventArgs) => KcAssemblyResolver.Resolve(eventArgs);
        Run(args);
        return;
    }

    static void Run(string[] args)
    {
        var login = new Login();
        login.EnableSecurityBoost = true;
        login.Login();
        login.ApplicationName = "KC.CM.Divalto";
        login.Version = "1.0";

        login.ValidateUser("KC.CM.Divalto.exe", false, "", "");

        var session = login.RuntimeSession;

        var activeBatch = session.NextBatchGet(login.ProcessID);

        MessageBox.Show("activeBatch.Name: " + activeBatch.Name);

        activeBatch.BatchClose(
             KfxDbState.KfxDbBatchReady, KfxDbQueue.KfxDbQueueNext, 0, "");

        var url = "http://localhost/webservice.asmx";

        var data1 = "data1";
        var data2 = "data2";
        var data3 = "data3";

        Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        data.Add("data1", data1);
        data.Add("data2", data2);
        data.Add("data3", data3);


        WsCaller wsCaller= new WsCaller();
        WsResponse returnValue =
            wsCaller.SoapApiCaller(url, data1, data2, data3);

        Console.WriteLine(returnValue);
        MessageBox.Show("returnValue" + returnValue);

        session.Dispose();
        login.Logout();
    }
  ```

  }

Here my test call is working and returns the webservice response. I need to get extracted fields values in order to pass them to the webservice.

My questions are the following:

- how do i get the data from KTM Server (the values that are displayed in KTM Validation module)
- how do i bypass the validation module depending on webservice response ? I should go to PDF Generator module if webservice response is positive
- how do i pass values returned by my web service to validation module ? For example, I expect a status message with error message, or data from web service. I would like to set a property

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the first part of my issue:

```
    static void Run(string[] args)
    {
      
        // MessageBox.Show("activeBatch.BatchFieldValue: " + activeBatch.BatchFieldValue);

        var url = "http://myurl/soap.asmx";
        try
        {
            var login = new Login();
            login.EnableSecurityBoost = true;
            login.Login();
            login.ApplicationName = "KC.CM.Divalto";
            login.Version = "1.0";

            login.ValidateUser("KC.CM.Divalto.exe", false, "", "");

            var session = login.RuntimeSession;
            // get the batch 
            var activeBatch = session.NextBatchGet(login.ProcessID);
            IACDataElement oRoot = activeBatch.ExtractRuntimeACDataElement(0);
            IACDataElement oBatch = oRoot.FindChildElementByName("Batch");
            // get the documents elt
            IACDataElement oDocument = oBatch.FindChildElementByName("Documents");
            IACDataElementCollection oDocColl = oDocument.FindChildElementsByName("Document");

           
            Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (IACDataElement oDoc in oDocColl)
            {
                IACDataElement oIndex = oDoc.FindChildElementByName("IndexFields");
                IACDataElementCollection oIndexColl = oIndex.FindChildElementsByName("IndexField");
                sw.WriteLine("Document: {0}", oDoc["UniqueID"].ToString());
                foreach (IACDataElement oField in oIndexColl)
                {
                    data.Add(oField["Name"].ToString(), oField["Value"].ToString());
                    sw.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Value: {1}", oField["Name"].ToString(), oField["Value"].ToString());
                }
                sw.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
                WsCaller wsCaller= new WsCaller();
  
  WsResponse returnValue =
      wsCaller.SoapApiCaller(url, data);
                var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                MessageBox.Show("data send" + js.Serialize(data));

                Console.WriteLine(returnValue);
                MessageBox.Show("returnValue" + returnValue);
            }
        }                    
        activeBatch.BatchClose(
             KfxDbState.KfxDbBatchReady, KfxDbQueue.KfxDbQueueNext, 0, "");
        session.Dispose();
        login.Logout();
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The data are stored in oIndexColl: with a foreach, i build my query... My dictionnary has a known size...